# Sharing GitHub pages templates and designs across project pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

What is the best approach to organizing GitHub pages so that I can define common elements (Jekyll templates, includes, CSS, JS) at the User/Organization level and leverage them in Project specific gh-pages sites.

I would like to keep the _posts and pages separate between projects.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Pages [support submodules](https://help.github.com/articles/using-submodules-with-pages), this way you could move any folder to its own repo (or another branch of the current repo).

This way you could reuse all the folders you want across many gh-pages repos, the only problem would be they won't update dynamically, so you would need to up the submodules in all the repos to use the latest code from them. Because of this you could want to use the static assets (CSS, JS) from either a single gh-pages instance, or move them to any non-github CDN.